# C# - Get the item type for Collection Types

Tags: c#, reflection

The items of `CookieCollection` collection are `Cookie`.
The items of another Collection may be `SomeType` etc

How can I find it out using reflection? 
I need to get the item type for Collection Types.

For example something `CookieCollection.ItemsType()` should return `Cookie`

possible?

Comment: Are you facing any issues while using GetType() method?

Comment: Why did you want to get `CookieCollection` by reflection?

Comment: I'm writing a De-Serializer I need to know each collection item type too.

Comment: Maybe checking out if the type has an indexer and if so, the return type of that indexer should be the type of all items. Or an `Add` method, etc.

Comment: By the way, the way you're asking the question, it sounds like you only care about `CookieCollection` in particular. You should be more clear.

Comment: @FurkanKambay how to get the type of the indexer?

Comment: @Nofuzy What is your underlying issue? **Why** do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

To find out by looking at the indexer:

```
public static Type GetCollectionItemType(Type collectionType)
{
    var intIndexer = collectionType.GetMethod("get_Item", new[] { typeof(int) });
    //var stringIndexer = collectionType.GetMethod("get_Item", new[] { typeof(string) });
    return intIndexer?.ReturnType ?? null; // null mean the type has no int indexer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
    public static Type GetIndexerType(this Type collectionType)
    {
        if (typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(collectionType))
        {
            var indexerProperty = collectionType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Item");
            if (indexerProperty != null)
            {
                return indexerProperty.PropertyType;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: However not all Collection's have an `Item` property.

Comment: @Magnus It's the name of an indexer, apparently. If a type has an indexer, you can't have a property named `Item` or a method named `get_Item` with the same parameters. (apparently, I just learned this by trying)

Comment: @FurkanKambay But `ICollection` does have such a property so there is no guarantee that you collection will have it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the  [**`Type.GetGenericArguments`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method for this purpose.

```
List<Foo> myList = ...

Type myListElementType = myList.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Comment: `CookieCollection` is not a generic collection.

Comment: you could use CookieCollection  as a object type class